# Oracle SOA Suite - Windows 8.1

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-soa

I have installed Oracle SOA Suite 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.5.0), Repository creation utility (11.1.1.5.0) and Web Logic server (10.3.6) on my operating system - Windows 8.1. I have read somewhere that these versions of the products are not compatible with Win8.1. Is it true? What do you think? Is there a way that I can use Oracle SOA Suite 11g over my OS.

Answer (score 1):

That the O.S. version is not certified doesn't necessarily mean that it won't work at all. If your purpose is only to install a sandbox environment then you can probably try, but not recommended for anything more than that. Alternate solutions would be to install a newer version of SOA Suite 11.1.1.9 or 12c, or even to deploy it into a VM with a supported O.S.

Comment: Exactly, so did I.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 is not supported for versions prior to 11.1.1.9. For more information and a reference: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html